# Big O notation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am learning Algorithm recently and know that there are usually some good algorithm existed already that we don't need to write our own. I think the problem I am facing in a question paper.
I have a question in my past paper that if a function is O(n) then can it be O(n^2) ?
can we say that if a function is O(n) then it's also O(n^2)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big O is an upper bound.  So, yes, n is in O(n^2), but not vice-versa.  Also, both n and n^2 are in O(n^3).